# prove common points of the circles

Tags: geometry

Let $ABC$ be an acute scalene triangle with
circumcenter $O$. Let $D$ be the foot of the
altitude from $A$ to the side $BC$. The lines
$BC$ and $AO$ intersect at $E$. Let $s$ be the line
through $E$ perpendicular to $AO$. The line $s$
intersects $AB$ and $AC$ at $K$ and $L$,
respectively. Denote by $w$ the circumcircle of
triangle $AKL$. Line $AD$ intersects $w$ again
at $X$.

Prove that w and the circumcircles of
triangles ABC and DEX have a common
point.

I am thinking if I should find the intersect points first, then determining if any of the intersection points are equal, but I am stil thinking that how should I find the intersect point....I am not sure if I am on the right track and the drawing is drawn by me, it isn't actually on the question....so will you correct me

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for. Here's a quick guide: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Comment: Hint: Prove that center I of $w$ lies on AD and AOI = 90°.